# how to resolve typescript error on React app

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I can't seem to fix some typescript error I get on my react app.

Code:

```
const [fetchJobTitlesCall, { data }] = useLazyQuery<Jobtitles, JobtitlesVariables>(JobTitlesQuery)
useEffect(() => {
    fetchJobTitlesCall({ variables: { keyword: 'Dev' } })
}, [fetchJobTitlesCall, data])

return (
            <Autocomplete
              onChange={(event, value) => dispatchJobTitlesFilter(value)}
              multiple
              id="tags-outlined"
              options={data?.jobTitles} // this line throwing error
              getOptionLabel={option => option.name + ` (${option.totalApplicants})`} // this line throwing error
              filterSelectedOptions
              renderInput={params => (
                <TextField
                  {...params}
                  onChange={event => fetchJobTitles(event.target.value)}
                  variant="outlined"
                  label="Search Job Title"
                  placeholder="Search Job Title"
                />
              )}
            />
)
```

Error:

> Type 'Jobtitles_jobTitles | undefined' is not assignable to type
>   'unknown[]'.   Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'unknown[]'.

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: I thing application fails to fetch jobTItle or jobTitle is not array type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing the type definition of `Autocomplete` it's difficult to tell exactly, but it looks like the `options` property requires an array (of unknown type). For example:

```
type Options = unknown[];
```

This requires it to *always* be an array, even an empty array. The following code will not work:

```
let options: Options;
const data = { jobTitles: undefined };
options = data.jobTitles; // same error
```

You can resolve this by defaulting to an empty array in case `jobTitles` is not known, for example:

```
options={data?.jobTitles || []}
```

This behavior may be undefined, though -- you might have to refer to the Autocomplete library itself to see how to handle this properly.

Answer (score 1):

The `options` property on the `Autocomplete` component is expecting the prop to be of type `unknown[]`. You need to handle the case where `data?.jobTitles` is `undefined`. You should be able to just default it to an empty array if the value is undefined.

```
options={data?.jobTitles || []}
```

Comment: thank you this also works, althou the other answer is more explainable!